# Set Up Navigation Hierarchy When Using External Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using an `NSObject` class called `MyClass` to be the data source and delegate for my tableView in my `UIViewController` class `MasterView`. When a cell is selected in MasterView`it pushes another ViewController called`DetailViewController`. How do I push`DetailViewController`from`MyClass` when it doesn't inherit a NavigationController?

My failed Attempts:

```
//This will push the view but I cant return afterward.
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

//This just does nothing
masterView = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
[masterView.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

MyClass can have a weak reference to MasterView (UIViewController) then the code [masterView.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES]; should work.

Comment: I placed `@property MasterViewController (weak) *masterView;` in my .h and removed `masterView = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];` but nothing happens and `masterView` returns nil